# Add new record to many-to-many relationship table in .net core ef

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have two models:

```
 public class Project : BaseEntity
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Code { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Client> Client { get; set; }
    }
```

```
    public class Client : BaseEntity
    {
        public string IdentityId { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Project> Projects { get; set; }
    }
```

And Im doing code first, and when I do seeding, it creates ClientProject table, however, I dont have that model in my context models.

So I now want to add some record to that table.
My try is as follows:

```
var client = _context.Clients.Where(x => !x.IsDeleted && x.Id == command.ClientId).FirstOrDefault();
var project = _context.Projects.Where(x => !x.IsDeleted && x.Id == command.ProjectId).FirstOrDefault();

//client.Projects = new ICollection<Project>(); because the next line throws Null reference exception
client.Projects.Add(project);

var r = await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
return r;
```

But Im having the null reference exception. I tried to initialize with commented line, but it doesnt recognize  `= new ICollection<Project>`
Any advice on this?

Comment: `=  new List<Project>()`

Comment: `ICollection` is an [interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/interfaces/) you can't instantiate interfaces in C#.

Comment: Yes, I know, now when I put `new List<Project>()` it works, but Im having another exception `System.InvalidOperationException: The instance of entity type 'Project' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'Id'} is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached. Consider using 'DbContextOptionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging' to see the conflicting key values.`

Comment: `var client = _context.Clients.Include(c => c.Projects).Where....` and skip the assignment. Or change client's `Projects` property to `public ICollection<Project> Projects { get; set; } = new List<Project>()`